# React reflux createStore $ajax trigger doesnt working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs, refluxjs

Hi I'm trying to get data updated with trigger but it dosn't working I'm new at react and reflux my part of code is:

```
import Reflux from 'reflux'
import $ from 'jquery'
import PeopleActions from  '../actions/PeopleActions.js'

let PeopleStore = Reflux.createStore({
    listenables: [PeopleActions],
    fetchPeople: function (){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://randomuser.me/api',
            dataType: 'json'
        })
        .done(function(peoples){
            let people = peoples.results
            this.trigger(people)
        })
    }
})

module.exports = PeopleStore
```

give me the next error:

```
PeopleStore.js?13fb:14 Uncaught TypeError: this.trigger is not a function
    at Object.eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:2617), <anonymous>:27:9)
    at fire (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:2623), <anonymous>:3317:31)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:2623), <anonymous>:3447:7)
    at done (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:2623), <anonymous>:9272:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:2623), <anonymous>:9514:9)
```

Comment: For what it's worth, you probably shouldn't be using jQuery with React. You don't want to change the DOM outside of React's virtual DOM, and if you're just trying to make an ajax request you should use fetch or an equivalent and not import an entire extensive library for that. That said, trigger() is a jQuery function so if you're trying to use a jquery function it should be like $(this).trigger(people)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is a strange mix of the `Store` concepts and the `Actions` concepts.  These are two related, but distinct, aspects of a flux flow.  I would recommend finding a guide of reflux and paying close attention to the distinction between those concepts.

Specifically, your function `fetchPeople` is an action, not a handler.  The store would want to have a different method named `onFetchPeople` with a very different definition than what you've written.

The error you have is completely expected, given that the concept of the "trigger" function only exists on actions, not stores.  But beyond that, it doesn't make much sense to try to trigger an action from within itself.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the old way in which Reflux worked. It should be something like this:

```
export default class PeopleStore extend Reflux.Store {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.listenables = PeopleActions;
    }

    fetchPeople() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://randomuser.me/api',
            dataType: 'json'
        })
        .done((peoples) => {
            let people = peoples.results
            this.setState(people)
        })
}
```

triggering `PeopleActions.fetchPeople()`, any store that listens to PeopleActions will trigger either `fetchPeople` or `onFetchPeople` from within the Store, depending on which of the functions exist.